# Why does the boundary change on definite integrals substitution

Tags: definite-integrals, substitution

I have this following Integral:

$$\int_0^2 (2x-1)^3 dx$$

I want to integrate it using u-substitution, like that:

$$u = 2x-1 $$
$${\frac{du}{dx}(2x + 1)} = 2$$
$$ {du = (2){dx}}$$
$$1/2\int (u)^3{du} $$

So far so good. After that I've got to change the boundaries in the integral, there comes the problem: I can't visualize this change graphically. I know that when

$$x = 0$$
$$u = -1$$

but I mean, if I plot
$$ (u)^3 $$
It doesn't have the same graph as
$$(2x-1)^3$$

How can they be equal?

I am sorry If it is a naive question and if I couldn't express myself right, I can clarify in the comments though

Thanks in advance

Comment: They're not supposed to be equal, that's why the second integral has a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ on the outside. It's saying that when you do the second integral, you'll get an area twice as big as the original, so we have to cut it in half to make it equal.

Comment: @NinadMunshi, when I say that the 'original' integral goes from 0 to 2 whereas the second integral (the transformed one) goes to -1 to 3... am I saying that the area beneath the graph from 0 to 2 on the first graph corresponds to the area from -1 to 3 on the second graph? btw, thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes that's right, but the second graph is $\frac{1}{2}u^3$, not just $u^3$. Then the interpretation of two different graphs, same areas will be correct.

Comment: @NinadMunshi, thanks a lot! Now I have a better understanding!

Answer (score 1):

Simplistic approach to address the question in your title:Let's take a look at a MUCH easier situation. Consider $y=4-x^2$ and consider the area under the curve from $x=-2$ to $x=2$. I think you can figure that out, right? Now let's translate this area $2$ units to the right. The function then becomes $y=4-(x-2)^2$. If I want to calculate the SAME area under the curve, how can I not have to move along the x-values of integration? Since the area literally has moved $2$ units to the right, in order to deal with the same region, there is no other way that I move those $x$ values $2$ units to the write as well. Now if you would perform a substitution on the $(x-2)^2$, by setting $x-2=t$, the idea of the substitution rule with respect to "tagging the boundary values along" becomes evident

Comment: thanks! It finally made me visualize graphically what was going on. On my example I cannot say that the graph moved, right? I mean, if we graph $$1/2(u)^3 $$ and $$(2x-1)^3 $$ they are not the same... but I guess it follows the same logic, is that correct?

Comment: Indeed it is not the same because there is "shrinking" involved as NINAD pointed out. But it essentially boils down to the same logic. You are "transforming" one area to some other area (either congruent or not) and the change of $x$ limits ensures that the numerical outcome of that area is the same

Comment: Thanks a lot, gotcha what you said!